# Model and context setting when foreign key contains null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a database and an EF Core 6.0 models and context. The main table (A) references two base tables (B and C), but the foreign key column in A may be null (value is added later via update). I try to list the records in the 1st round.

In the `ExpressionMetaDataProvider.cs` I get an exception at return func(model):

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I guess the problem is that the foreign key column may (does) contain null.

Model of the main table (relevant part):

```
[ForeignKey("FinInspAction")]
[InverseProperty("ImpregnalasNewFinInspActionNavigation")]
public virtual ImpregnationCac FinInspActionNavigation { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("FinInspCode")]
[InverseProperty("ImpregnalasNewFinInspCodeNavigation")]
public virtual ImpregnationAcc FinInspCodeNavigation { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("StartChkAction")]
[InverseProperty("ImpregnalasNewStartChkActionNavigation")]
public virtual ImpregnationCac StartChkActionNavigation { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("StartChkCode")]
[InverseProperty("ImpregnalasNewStartChkCodeNavigation")]
public virtual ImpregnationAcc StartChkCodeNavigation { get; set; }`
```

Model of the 1st referenced table:

```
[InverseProperty("FinInspCodeNavigation")]
public virtual ICollection<ImpregnalasNew>? ImpregnalasNewFinInspCodeNavigation {get;set;}
[InverseProperty("StartChkCodeNavigation")]
public virtual ICollection<ImpregnalasNew>? ImpregnalasNewStartChkCodeNavigation {get;set;}`
```

Model of the 2nd referenced table:

```
[InverseProperty("FinInspActionNavigation")]
public virtual ICollection<ImpregnalasNew> ImpregnalasNewFinInspActionNavigation {get;set; }
[InverseProperty("StartChkActionNavigation")]
public virtual ICollection<ImpregnalasNew> ImpregnalasNewStartChkActionNavigation {get;set; }`
```

In the `DbContext` file, I tried to add the `IsRequired(false)` to avoid integrity check:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ImpregnalasNew>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.GoodTry).IsFixedLength();

    entity.Property(e => e.PrevStepDone).IsFixedLength();

    entity.HasOne(d => d.FinInspActionNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.ImpregnalasNewFinInspActionNavigation)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.FinInspAction)**.IsRequired(false)**
        .HasConstraintName("IMPREGNALAS_NEW_IMPREGNAT_FK3");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.FinInspCodeNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.ImpregnalasNewFinInspCodeNavigation)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.FinInspCode)**.IsRequired(false)**
        .HasConstraintName("IMPREGNALAS_NEW_IMPREGNAT_FK2");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.StartChkActionNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.ImpregnalasNewStartChkActionNavigation)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.StartChkAction)**.IsRequired(false)**
        .HasConstraintName("IMPREGNALAS_NEW_IMPREGNAT_FK4");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.StartChkCodeNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.ImpregnalasNewStartChkCodeNavigation)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.StartChkCode)**.IsRequired(false)**
        .HasConstraintName("IMPREGNALAS_NEW_IMPREGNAT_FK1");
});
```

This doesn't seem to be enough, however, `IsRequired` function's purpose is just this, as far as I understand.

Could you please help me to move on with this issue? I found many hints, but none of them worked yet. Thank you!

I tried to set navigation properties and column data types nullable by ?, but it didn't help.